Custom localstack docker image
In order to speed up my integration tests execution, I'd like to have a custom localstack pro container with some aws resources already created.
Basically I start a docker compose file with the below configuration, run some awslocal and tflocal commands, then stop the container and run docker commit, but when I run the saved container the changes I made are not there.
I was able to use this same strategy for the same purpose with postgres(start a postgres container, run some migrations with liquibase, run docker commit), but in that case I had to use the PGDATA variable to have the changes persisted when docker commit runs.
Does localstack has some particularity for this use case?
version: "3.8"

services:
  localstack:
    container_name: "${LOCALSTACK_DOCKER_NAME:-localstack-main}"
    image: localstack/localstack-pro:3.8
    ports:
      # Now only required if you need to access LocalStack from the host
      - "127.0.0.1:4566:4566"
      # Now only required if you need to access LocalStack from the host
      - "127.0.0.1:4510-4559:4510-4559"
    environment:
      - LOCALSTACK_AUTH_TOKEN=$LOCALSTACK_AUTH_TOKEN
      - DEBUG=1
      - PERSISTENCE=1 
      - SNAPSHOT_SAVE_STRATEGY=ON_REQUEST
      - LAMBDA_RUNTIME_ENVIRONMENT_TIMEOUT=300
      - LAMBDA_DOCKER_NETWORK=digital-localstack_ls
    volumes:
      - "${LOCALSTACK_VOLUME_DIR:-./localstack-volume}:/var/lib/localstack"
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
    networks:
      ls:
        # Set the container IP address in the 10.0.2.0/24 subnet
        ipv4_address: 10.0.2.20


In most cases containers keep persistent data in volumes (possibly an anonymous volume declared in the Dockerfile) and docker commit doesn't preserve those.  In general docker commit is rarely if ever a best practice (it is hard to reproduce the committed image and all but impossible to upgrade the included software) and I'd try to find a different workflow to meet your needs.

You have volume mounted. As per docker documentation commit doesn't contain changes in volume or bind mount. So, Just remove volumes and use COPY to copy data of ${LOCALSTACK_VOLUME_DIR:-./localstack-volume}
